# Change a textview in a fragment based on the DialogAlert positive/negative buttons in Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am building a quiz app that has two types of questionnaires. I have a DialogAlert that allows the user to choose which questionnaire (two options: either "history" or "chemistry") they want to complete and have the results display in a fragment.

My goal is to be able to display the textview ("history" or "chemistry") that the questionnaire they selected in the result fragment.

I have a `Dialog` class:

```
public class DialogAlert extends DialogFragment {
private Context context;
    String selection;
   
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] items = {"History", "Chemistry"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select a topic to complete")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selection = items[which];
                    }
                })

                // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        switch (selection)
                        {
                            case("History"):
                                Intent intent_hist = new Intent(getActivity(), historyquestions.class);
                                startActivity(intent_hist);
                                break;
                            case("Chemistry"):
                                Intent intent_chem = new Intent(getActivity(), chemistryquestions.class);
                                startActivity(intent_chem);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No topic was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

My `Result` fragment in which I have a placeholder textview that I want to display what the user had selected (either history or chemistry) based on the positive/ negative button above:

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment{
TextView topic  
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);       
topic = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
return layoutView;
}
}
```

How should I approach this? The challenge is that the result is shown in one of the fragments and I am unsure how would I "pass" what the user had selected in the `Dialog` to the `Result` fragment. Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

*Edit with the home fragment Id

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.homeFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="300">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                android:text="Selection of topic"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topic"
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                    android:text="Topic"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit 2023-02-13

`HomeViewModel` class:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is a home fragment");
    }

    // getText method
    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    // function to update the mText value
    public void setText(String updateText) {
        mText.setValue(updateText);
    }
}
```

`homeFragment` class:

```
       import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
       import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
       import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
         
       public class homeFragment extends Fragment{
                        
            private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    
            View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        
    homeViewModel =                    
  ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);                        
    
    final TextView topic = (TextView)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
                          homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                            topic.setText(s);
                       }
                        });
                return layoutView;
               }
```

`Dialog` class:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import com.example.quizzApp.MainActivity;
import com.example.quizzApp.ui.home.HomeViewModel;

public class DialogAlert extends DialogFragment {
    private Context context;
    String selection;
    private HomeViewModel model;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] items = {"History", "Chemistry"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        // Set the dialog title
        builder.setTitle("Select a topic to complete")
                // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
                // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selection = items[which];
                    }
                })

                // Set the action buttons
                // User clicked OK, so save the selectedItems results somewhere
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        switch (selection)
                        {
                            case("History"):
                                model.setText("History");
                                Intent intent_hist = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent_hist);
                                break;
                            case("Chemistry"):
                                model.setText("Chemistry");
                                Intent intent_chem = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent_chem);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No topic was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scenario

You have created an App with Bottom Navigation Activity template. There should be 3 tabs `Home`, `Dashboard`, `Notifications`. And somehow you have opened a `DialogFragment` and that allows you to choose between `History` or `Chemistry` as the topic. And upon selecting either one and press **OK**, your `Home` fragment should display the topic selected.

---

#### Possible solution

If you are using Bottom Navigation Activity template, there should be a `HomeViewModel` class. You can make use of this `HomeViewModel` class, share it among different Fragments, and update the view accordingly.

`HomeFragment` class:

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private Button btnDialog;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Please notice the below line, getting ViewModel using the below method can ensure
        //  the model can be shared across different Fragments
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
                // new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        // You have registered the ViewModel to change your HomeFragment TextView. So if the value
        //  of mText has been updated, the TextView in HomeFragment will also be updated 
        //  accordingly.
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        // This btnDialog is just my testing button, it is a button to open your mentioned
        //  DialogFragment. So you can ignore this button and the openDialog(View) function.
        btnDialog = root.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
        btnDialog.setOnClickListener(this::openDialog);
        return root;
    }

    // As mentioned above, this function can be ignored
    public void openDialog(View v) {
        DialogAlert frag = new DialogAlert();
        frag.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "DialogAlert");
    }
}
```

`HomeViewModel` class:

```java
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    // You need to add a function so that you can update mText value
    public void setText(String updateText) {
        mText.setValue(updateText);
    }
}
```

`DialogAlert` class:

```java
public class DialogAlert extends DialogFragment {
    private Context context;
    String selection;
    // Define a variable to hold the ViewModel class
    private HomeViewModel model;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Obtain the HomeViewModel so that we can update the value of mText and sync to view in
        //  HomeFragment
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] items = {"History", "Chemistry"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select a topic to complete")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selection = items[which];
                    }
                })

                // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        switch (selection) {
                            case ("History"):
                                // Magic line, it will trigger the onChanged() in HomeFragment
                                model.setText("History");
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;
                            case ("Chemistry"):
                                // Magic line, it will trigger the onChanged() in HomeFragment
                                model.setText("Chemistry");
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No topic was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

With the above code, after you have selected the option in `DialogFragment`, your `HomeFragment` TextView should be updated at once.

---

#### Misconception

Regarding on the following code:

```java
switch (selection)
{
    case("History"):
        Intent intent_hist = new Intent(getActivity(), historyquestions.class);
        startActivity(intent_hist);
        break;
    case("Chemistry"):
        Intent intent_chem = new Intent(getActivity(), chemistryquestions.class);
        startActivity(intent_chem);
        break;
}
```

The above code will start an `Activity` to either `historyquestions` Activity or `chemistryquestions` Activity (if you have properly created these Activity), instead of proceeding to your result `homeFragment` Fragment.

---

#### Additional Note

It is a good practice to follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) when you name classes. For example:

- *homeFragment* should be named as **HomeFragment**
- *historyquestions* should be named as **HistoryQuestions**

Comment: Thank you for the new suggestions! I made use my `HomeViewModel` and followed exactly (with the DialogAlert class) as the suggested codes. The text in `HomeFragment`shows only "This is home fragment" regardless of the options I selected from the Dialog. I am thinking that the value is not being updated yet `mText.setValue(updateText);` in this line

Comment: Just want to make sure the import in `HomeFragment` is correct: `import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;` and `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;` and `import androidx.annotation.Nullable;`

Comment: Yes, the import you have is correct. Can I confirm again in your ```HomeFragment```, when you are assigning ```homeViewModel```, are you doing like this: ```homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);```?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the response. I have exactly like this: `homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);`

Comment: And it is only showing `This is home fragment` as output. I put the debug stopping point at `textView.setText(s);` and I got s = This is home fragment which seems that the `mText.setValue(updateText);` is not getting the updates to overwrite the `s`

Comment: Could you edit the question and show some updated codes on ```DialogAlert``` class, ```HomeViewModel``` class, ```HomeFragment``` class and the XML of ```HomeFragment```? I need to look further to see what is missing.

Comment: I updated the codes with the same `XML` of `homeFragment`. Can you take a look? Thank you very much for your time!!

Comment: Is it necessary for you to include these 2 lines after pressing OK button for your ```DialogFragment```? ```Intent intent_hist = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);``` and ```startActivity(intent_hist);```. You can comment out these 2 lines and see if it works. Because if you are calling these 2 lines, it will create another ```Activity``` which probably loads another new set of your ```Fragment```. Removing these 2 lines will instead return to your initial ```HomeFragment``` and the value should be updated there.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My current `DialogAlert` is a standalone activity that after pressing the `OK` button, it will bring the user to either the history/ chemistry questionnaires first. After the user answer it will display the result in `homeFragment`. Therefore, I tried comment out the two intent line but it didl not be able to show me any next activities - not even getting back to the `homeFragment` page...

Comment: Just want to clarify that if we have `intent` we will re-load the activity and does not memorize the user's choice in another activity (e.g., `DialogAlert`)? I am just not able to text and verify the results yet based on my current setup. And I am trying to find a way to work around this issue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251879/discussion-between-enowneb-and-swiftlearneer).